# Removing all non-ascii characters from a workflow (file)

Tags: text-processing, ascii

How would I remove all non-ascii characters from one file? Would there be a specific command to perform this?

```
grep --colour='auto' -P -n'[^\x00-\x7]' /usr/local/...
```

I believe this finds the characters within the workflow, but how would I remove all the instances of the characters in question?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15133607/how-to-remove-non-ascii-char-using-sed

Comment: related: if you just want to avoid problems with control chars (instead of silently getting rid of them), you can simply use `cat -v` to show them in ASCII represantation for them.  (eg. `^G` for `\007`)

Comment: When you say "non-ascii characters" do you also include accented characters?

Comment: @MatijaNalis More info about the representation: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Caret_notation

Comment: What is the use case? Very often there are specific tools or different approaches which work much better than simply removing a bunch of special characters. Please note that ASCII does include several "special" characters like vertical tabs, bell, and NUL - are you sure you don't mean *printable* characters?

Answer (score 33):

ASCII characters are [characters in the range from 0 to 177 (octal) inclusively](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/isascii.html).

To delete characters outside of this range in a file, use

```
LC_ALL=C tr -dc '\0-\177' <file >newfile
```

[The `tr` command is a utility that works on single characters](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/tr.html), either substituting them with other single characters (transliteration), deleting them, or compressing runs of the same character into a single character.

The command above would read from `file` and write the modified content to `newfile`.  The `-d` option to `tr` makes the utility delete characters (instead of transliterating them), and `-c` makes it consider characters outside the given interval (instead of inside).

`LC_ALL=C` makes sure that every byte value makes up a valid character. Without it, some `tr` implementations would abort if they found sequences of bytes that don't form valid characters in the locale's character encoding.

---

To replace the original file with the modified one, use

```
LC_ALL=C tr -dc '\0-\177' <file >newfile &&
mv newfile file
```

This renames the new file to the name of the old file after `tr` has completed successfully. If `tr` does not complete successfully, either because it could not read the original file or not write to the new file, the original file will be left unchanged.

Alternatively, to preserve as much as possible of the meta data (permissions etc.) of the original file, use

```
cp file tmpfile &&
LC_ALL=C tr -dc '\0-\177' <tmpfile >file &&
rm tmpfile
```

Comment: What would be the problem if `LC_ALL=C` is not used for `tr`?

Comment: @Isaac That was Stéphane's edit. I'm assuming he knows better than me. He explains: `LC_ALL=C` makes sure that every byte value makes up a valid character. Without it, some `tr` implementations would abort if they found sequences of bytes that don't form valid characters in the locale's character encoding.

Answer (score 16):

With `perl`

```
perl -pi -e 's/[^[:ascii:]]//g'
```

Answer (score 10):

If all you need is a regex: `[\x00-\x7F]`.
That you could apply to several utilities:

```
<file LC_ALL=C   sed   's/[^\o0-\o177]//g'      # GNU sed not POSIXLY_CORRECT
<file LC_ALL=C   awk   '{gsub(/[^\0-\177]/,"");print}'
<file            perl  -pe 's/[^[:ascii:]]//g;'
<file            tr    -dc '\0-\177'
```

Understand that sed, awk, and perl expect "text files" as defined in Unix. All work well in such case. But specifically, awk adds a trailing new line (whether it existed in the source file or not) (replacing print with printf could remove ALL newlines on the input). The `tr` is designed to work with any file type.
However the NUL (`\0`) is not a valid character in a [POSIX text file](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/basedefs/V1_chap03.html#tag_03_403) and should be avoided:

> The lines do not contain NUL characters...

In fact, many control characters would generate other problems under some specific conditions.
So, probably you need `[\x07-\x0d\x20-\x7e]`

```
<file LC_ALL=C   sed   's/[^\o007-\o015\o040-\o176]//g'            # GNU sed without POSIXLY_CORRECT
<file LC_ALL=C   awk   '{gsub(/[^\0-\15\40-\176]/,"");print}'
<file            perl  -pe 's/[^\x{7}-\x{d}\x{20}-\x{7e}]//g;'
<file            tr    -dc '\7-\15\40-\176'
```

The range 7-13 (in decimal) is `\a\b\t\n\v\f\r` (in order).
A similar (probably more portable) range could be written as `[^[:space:][:print:]] (similar because it doesn't include` \a\b` --bell and backspace--).

```
<file LC_ALL=C   sed   's/[^[:space:][:print:]]//g'  # GNU sed without POSIXLY_CORRECT
<file LC_ALL=C   awk   '{gsub(/[^[:space:][:print:]]/,"");print}'
<file            perl   -pe 's/[^[:space:][:print:]]//g;'
<file            tr     -dc '[:space:][:print:]'
```

Related:
[Regex any ASCII character](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3203210/9110606)
[Perl solution](https://www.perlmonks.org/?node_id=619792)
[Posix Text File](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/basedefs/V1_chap03.html#tag_03_403)

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas What is the limitation of GNU sed that makes the syntax GNU specific (I understand the POSIXLY_CORRECT problem).

Comment: `[^\o0]` is to match on characters other than backslash, o and 0 in POSIX `sed` (in all implementations but GNU sed). That's not a _limitation_ of GNU `sed` but a non-compliant extension, which is why it's disabled when POSIXLY_CORRECT is in the environment).

Comment: Note that technically, that `\0` is not POSIX (behaviour undefined), but any way awk's behaviour is unspecified if the input has NUL bytes.

Comment: Then: The limitation of GNU sed is to fail to avoid accepting escaped characters inside bracket expressions. That is: posix compatible action is to not accept `\t` as a tab inside bracket expressions. Correct? . @StéphaneChazelas

Comment: More than a year and still no answer @StéphaneChazelas. What would be the posix way to write a tab character inside a range? some thing like `$'[\t]'`? That is using an also non-compliant shell feature to place a tab inside a pair of brackets `[]`.

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas `tr` should correctly process NUL characters according to posix: read Rationale in [*However, the removal of -n in a later proposal does not remove the requirement that tr correctly process NUL characters in its input stream.*](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/tr.html)